# How to do alphanumeric validation in sencha touch for textfield

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

How do I implement alphanumeric validation in Sencha Touch for `textfield`? I have tried this way:

```
regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/,
regexText: 'Invalid value in field',
```

But it is not showing any error when I type the `#` symbol or any other special character.

Comment: According to docs : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.0/#!/api/Ext.field.Text   Textfield component has no "Regex" properties (but in ExtJs it has). I think you should check the value on the change event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @Benoit Cuvelier in the comments:

> According to docs: [docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.0/#!/api/Ext.field.Text](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.0/#!/api/Ext.field.Text)
>   Textfield component has no "Regex" properties (but in ExtJs it has). I
>   think you should check the value on the change event

That said, a simple implementation using the `keyup` listener could be:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    label: 'Only alphanumeric values',
    name: 'alphanumeric',
    regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/,
    listeners: {
        keyup: function(field) {
            var value = field.getValue();
            if (value.length && !value.match(field.config.regex)) {
                field.setStyle('border: 1px solid red;');
            } else {
                field.setStyle('border: 0;');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ttl

Comment: this is not working in sencha touch because regex is not sencha touch configuration

Comment: I linked a fiddle where it's working. I am using the `field.config.regex` configuration in my own code, it's not a Sencha configuration. At least try it before saying it doesn't work.

Comment: Then you must be doing something wrong because the fiddle is working. Good luck with the debugging!